# working with special character forward slash '\' or backward slash '/' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, special-characters, sql-like

I am storing the full-path details of the file in a table with its name and Id assigned to it. 
Now for retrieving the row on the query below

```
select *
     from path_table
     where path = 'D:\\\WorkBench\\\Demo\\\sample.txt'
```

This is working fine .

How can I get the same result with 'like' in MySQL

```
select *
     from path_table
     where path like 'D:\\\WorkBench\\Demo\\\sample.txt'
```

This statement returns 0 rows. 
 Actually I need something like  if I give

```
select *
     from path_table
     where path like 'D:\\\WorkBench\\\Demo\\\'
```

It should return all rows I.e. files under same path so need to use like with '%'. But its not working. What should I use instead?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
select * from path_table where path like '%D:\\WorkBench\\Demo\\%'
```

You forgot to put this sign (%) in the starting and ending.

note:I put % sign in the starting also because may be there were some characters added in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried this

```
select * from path_table where path like 'D:\WorkBench\Demo\%'
```

Insted of ths

```
select * from path_table where path like 'D:\WorkBench\\Demo\\%'
```

Also, try using the full path at first like this:

```
select * from path_table where path like 'D:\\WorkBench\\Demo\\sample.txt'
```